# Как сделать размытие текста,как в фигме

Tags: css, css3

Как сделать размытие такого цвета #43632B сзади текста : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мб это просто бэкграунд градиент?

Answer (score 0):

```css
p{
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 20px #43632B , 0 0 40px#43632B , 0 0 80px #43632B ; 
}
```

```html
<p>фигма</p>
```